# Powershell Invoke-CImMethod type mismatch

Tags: powershell

Why does this work?

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root/CIMV2/TerminalServices" -ClassName "Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings" | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName "SetIPAndPort" -Arguments @{TransportType=1; IPAddress="*"; Port=4443; OverrideExisting=1}
```

But this:

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace "root/CIMV2/TerminalServices" -ClassName "Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings" -MethodName "SetIPAndPort" -Arguments @{TransportType=1; IPAddress="*"; Port=4443; OverrideExisting=1}
```

Gives an error:

> Invoke-CimMethod : Type mismatch for parameter "Port"

The *Port* argument should be an *unit16* I can cast it as such but then it trips over the other boolean values.

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace "root/CIMV2/TerminalServices" -ClassName "Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings" -MethodName "SetIPAndPort" -Arguments @{TransportType=1; IPAddress="*"; Port=[uint16]4443; OverrideExisting=1}
```

> Invoke-CimMethod : Type mismatch for parameter "OverrideExisting"

I don't understand why using *Get-CimInstance* changes anything about casting variables.

Comment: "I can cast it as such but then it trips over the other boolean values." - can you show us your attempt at casting it?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I edited my post accordingly. Casting the boolean values as [boolean]$value doesn't work for those values.

Comment: Why are you passing an integer value to `OverrideExisting` if it expects a boolean? Try `@{TransportType=1; IPAddress="*"; Port=[uint16]4443; OverrideExisting=$true}` instead

Comment: `Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace "root/CIMV2/TerminalServices" -ClassName "Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings" -MethodName "SetIPAndPort" -Arguments @{TransportType=[uint16]1; IPAddress="*"; Port=[uint16]4443; OverrideExisting=$true}` should be correct but throws an error: Invalid method Parameter(s)

Comment: But that just means that one of the values falls outside what the interface expects - at least the _types_ are correct :)

Comment: That seems to be the case, but all parameters are exactly as documented [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/setipandport-win32-tsgatewayserversettings) , and the first statement in my post does the job just fine which is rather odd.

Comment: I think the difference is that when you call `Invoke-CimMethod` on its own, it's interpreted as a request to invoke a _static_ method, whereas when you pipe an instance to `Invoke-CimMethod`, it's clear that you want to invoke an _instance method_ on it

Comment: Have you tried the older way?  `$class = [wmiclass]'root/CIMV2/TerminalServices:Win32_TSGatewayServerSettings'; $class.SetIpAndPort(); $class.SetIPAndPort(1, '*', 4443, 1)`   I don't have this class or if the order of the args is right.

Comment: I meant `$class.SetIPAndPort` to see the declarations.